# Grease Pencil Fill material covering up the existing outlines and not filling properly due to the appearance of an unknown light blue line

Tags: materials, grease-pencil

I'm learning Blender for the first time.
I've been following along with Grease Pencil tutorials on YouTube.

1. When I fill the material, it tends to cover up the outlines I drew previously. In the tutorial, the existing lines are preserved well. What could be the difference?
2. Also, when I click on "Fill Color," a blue guide line-like thing appears. What is its purpose? It seems to be preventing the color from filling properly.

Note: The translation above is provided based on the context and assumes that you are discussing Blender's features related to Grease Pencil and material filling. If the context is different, please provide more details, and I'll be glad to help accordingly.[image]